# How far can I run 55 amps (240 volts) down a NM 6-2 cable and still meet code?

Tags: load

I'm running a 240 Volts, 45 amps down a NM 6-2 cable.  How long can this wire be and still meet electrical code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You had 55/240 in your title and 45/220 in your post. Please fix that ambiguity. If you're in the U.S., nominal voltages are 120/240.

Comment: 1 - Code does not always mandate maximum voltage drop. Location matters - country/state/(possibly) city. 2 - BM normally only usable *inside* a building. There are other types of cable for outside. Is this actually inside or outside? 3 - What are you connecting? In most places, you can use larger aluminum wire instead and save a LOT of money, even if upsized to compensate for voltage drop, but it may depend on what you are connecting as well as where you are.

Comment: If I understand correctly that 3% is actually enshrined in Code in Canada and your 6/2 is copper, 180 feet for 45 Amps. If you are not in Canada, 3% is not enshrined in code. 147.5 feet for 55 Amps. **If the NM wire leaves the building, it's not code-legal anywhere.**

Comment: (not "BM" (typo, can't change after 5 minutes...) should be "NM").

Comment: The NEC is noticeably vague, and lots of if/ands/or/buts can apply. The general recommendation is a total of no more than 5% loss, which 55A@240v calculates to about 250 feet. I would have serious reservations about recommending that without real details, including service quality.

Comment: What are you trying to run off this NM cable?

Answer (score 1):

NM isn't allowed outside. So limitation #1 is the size of your building.

The stuff is obscenely expensive, and there are ways of getting *more* usefulness from *far less* money. So "the limits of your money" is limitation #2 and "limits of good judgment" is #3.

If you were in Canada, there'd be some funny stuff about 3%, but that only arises if the run length is 180'. In the US you get to decide that for yourself based on the actual load.

I know you've done earnest research and that research feels complete to you. But tell us more about what you're doing.  I bet we can help with a more cost effective alternative.